# Can underground pools have windows between them and basements?

Tags: the-sims-3

I've seen videos of people making pools on the second floor (and higher up) in houses, and put large windows in them so you could see your sims swimming from the other side of the window. I tried this but underground: building a basement bordering on a pool and putting a window in between them. But for some reason I am unable to put them next to one another: there stays a square in between them with a message from the game.

Am I doing it wrong, or is it impossible to do in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible but only with cheats that allow you to place things without restrictions.

open the cheatconsole and type `moveobjects on`. Now you can place everything wherever you want without restrictions.
Please be aware that cou can delete items that normally cannot be deleten or sold such as your trashcan or sims themself.

You disable this cheat mode by restarting your game or typing `moveobjects off` in your cheat console.

[image]
<sub>Have fun with your non-common placed windows.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tutorials in Internet to do what you want. For example see [this one](http://forum.thesims3.com/jforum/posts/list/0/291244.page).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Link only answers are generally discouraged.  Describe the solution in brief that the link provides.

Comment: I know that, but this is a tutorial with a lot of steps and screenshots. I can't write a smaller solution. Also, I think that doesn't justify the downvote: at least I have provided something useful, and -1 < 0 = nothing.

Comment: @Mabus at least, provide 6-7 words describing what the link provides. I'd write your answer like this: _Basically, you need to draw the basement first, then draw the pool. For details, please check [this detailed tutorial](http://forum.thesims3.com/jforum/posts/list/0/291244.page)_

Comment: i upvoted too. meanwhile it has 0 points instead of -2. sure, some people dislike the use of external links but i think it's totally fine